# Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED )) in UWP app

Tags: uwp-xaml

While opening the MainPage.xaml after creating new uwp project getting error

Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and repaired it still I am getting the same error. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file and select "Open With.." > "Automatic Editor Selector (XML)"

Comment: Tried to open with Automatic Editor Selector (XML) then getting the error "Visual Studio has encountered an unexpected error". Reinstalled Visual studio but the issue isn't resolved. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10

Comment: Deleting '.vs' hidden folder under your project root folder also can help.

Comment: I'm having this error at runtime whenever I try to get `App.Resources`.

Answer (score 0):

I would right-click the .xaml file and "Open with..." and select 'Xaml Designer' or 'Xaml Designer with Encoding' and this would bring up the xml text file.  If I try to open with 'Automatic Selector' I get the exception popup.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that was throwing the error was the connected services functions. I could not add or maintain them.

I had to restore my entire code base to resolve the issue. I pulled the last stable build and then reintroduced my changes until I had it stable again.

We have a fairly large WPF code base comprised of VB, XAML and C#. We use a hosted SQL Server database and that is what the connected services were for. I only noticed the problem when I was attempting to add a new table. I should add, we use netTiers to created the classes for the hosted data.

I was not able to determine the exact cause because only a total wipe and reload worked. I do suspect that an MSI project I worked on that used WIX was the culprit. That is because I am the only developer to use those and the only one who experienced this issue.

So a lot of conjecture, I admit, but starting with a clean stable build from another developer solved the issue.